# Import arbitrary Python script with main __name__

Tags: python

I have a wrapper script `wrapper.py`, in which I modify the environment, `sys.path` and others. One thing that the wrapper script should then do is to execute an arbitrary other Python script, say `foo.py`, and make `__name__` of `foo.py` be `"main"`.

Is there a way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

using python 3.6, I was able to get this to work.

```
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader
SourceFileLoader("__main__", "foo.py").load_module()
```